# Maximise $t(1-t)(1+t)$ if $0<t<1$ using arithmetic and Geometric mean ( Basically No Calculus )

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A function $f(t)=t(1-t)(1+t)$ where t belongs to $(0,1)$. 
Find the maximum value of the function using am-gm, i don't want to use calculus to answer the question. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality, we have for $\alpha\in(0,1)$,
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{\alpha(1-\alpha)}(\alpha t)(1-t)(1-\alpha+(1-\alpha)t)\leq\frac{1}{\alpha(1-\alpha)}\left[\frac{2-\alpha}{3}\right]^3\tag{*}
$$
with equality iff $\alpha t=1-t=1-\alpha+(1-\alpha)t$. Solving $\alpha t=1-t$ yields $t=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$ whereas solving $\alpha t=(1-\alpha)+(1-\alpha)t$ yields $t=\frac{1-\alpha}{2\alpha-1}$. Reconciling these 2 solutions forces $\alpha$ to be $\sqrt{3}-1$. So the maximum value is obtained when $t=1/\sqrt{3}$ and the maximal value is the rightmost expression of (*) evaluated at $\alpha=\sqrt{3}-1$, which simplifies to $\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: awesome. now is there a method to maximise any cubic whose roots are a,b,c.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I don't know but for specific problems, you might try the method I used here. I wrote the solution this way to show my thought process.

Comment: is there a book from where i can read and get many problems on am - gm. You did not change the factor (1-t) at all... why?... is there a general rule to tackle such questions..

Comment: I could have changed $1-t$, the result would still be the same. For this problem, there is a hint about using AM-GM so the obvious thing is to play around with the factors until they sum to a constant. Your more general question has been asked here so you can search around. Good luck!